# How execute sh command using Shake

Tags: haskell, shake-build-system

I'm trying to migrate an existing makefile to Shake and so far I've tried the following (just create a file with the content of a directory)

```
module Main where
import Development.Shake

main :: IO ()
main = shakeArgs shakeOptions{shakeFiles="_build"} $ do
    let ls = "_build/ls.txt"
    want [ls]
    ls *> \out ->  do
        cmd "ls >  " out
```

When I run it, I get the following error message :

```
> runghc test.hs _build/ls.txt
# ls (for _build/ls.txt)
ls: >: No such file or directory
ls: _build/ls.txt: No such file or directory
Error when running Shake build system:
* _build/ls.txt
Development.Shake.cmd, system command failed
Command: ls > _build/ls.txt
Exit code: 1
Stderr:
ls: >: No such file or directory
ls: _build/ls.txt: No such file or directory
```

What Am I doing wrong? How do you execute a `sh` command and redirect its output?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To start with the conversion you probably want:

```
cmd Shell "ls >" out
```

The argument `Shell` tells Shake to use the system shell, meaning the redirect works. Later on you may wish to switch to:

```
Stdout result <- cmd "ls"
writeFile' out result
```

Now you are not invoking the shell, but capturing the output with Shake. Sometime later, you may wish to switch to:

```
getDirectoryFiles "." ["*"]
```

Which is the Shake tracked way of getting a list of files.

Comment: `Shell` works indeed. Why is it needed then ? I thought `cmd` was already running a shell command, isn't it ?

Comment: Nope, `cmd` is running the command directly, through something like `exec` (if this were C). Avoiding `Shell` often gives more predictable behaviour cross-platform, avoids starting the shell, makes escaping much simpler etc.